# Does Android SQLite cursor load all records into memory at once?

Tags: android, sqlite

Does an Android SQLite cursor load all data for a query into memory, or is there some sort of optimization strategy that's part of its implementation?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you expect that SQLite cursors have a different default behaviour on Android compared to other platforms?

Comment: @LevLandau: I don't have that expectation.  But since I'm specifically interested in SQLite on Android, I made my question as narrow as possible.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/QX0pI5bth8I)

Comment: Cursor is temporary storage.It store data for some while .It directly load in memory.we can not optimize after loading in memory

Comment: @LevLandau Android used `SQLite` library (C/C++ library). But SQLite publishes many methods for customize. So maybe Android platform will be different from others. For example, as my research, in Android, windows size of cursor is about 2MB. But maybe different at other platform.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `SQLiteCursor` fills a "window" with data as you navigate through it. My recollection is that the window size is 1MB, but I can't point you to specific code that backs up that recollection. So, for small queries, the net effect is that the `SQLiteCursor` will hold the entire result set in memory, once you start accessing rows and columns.

Comment: In SDK 23.0.1. It's 2MB. Please view my answer

Comment: What happens after the memory limit? Does the cursor need to go back and do a database read from the UI thread to get more data?

Comment: @whizzle: Presumably.

Comment: It looks like the source code confirms the `SQLiteCursor` fills a window: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.java

Answer (score 13):

Thanks for [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) about `Window` term so I reversed again Android by navigating those classes `SQLiteCursor -> AbstractWindowedCursor -> CursorWindow` . Here is `CursorWindow` constructor:

```
 public CursorWindow(String name) {
        mStartPos = 0;
        mName = name != null && name.length() != 0 ? name : "<unnamed>";
        if (sCursorWindowSize < 0) {
            /** The cursor window size. resource xml file specifies the value in kB.
             * convert it to bytes here by multiplying with 1024.
             */
            sCursorWindowSize = Resources.getSystem().getInteger(
                com.android.internal.R.integer.config_cursorWindowSize) * 1024;
        }
        mWindowPtr = nativeCreate(mName, sCursorWindowSize);
        if (mWindowPtr == 0) {
            throw new CursorWindowAllocationException("Cursor window allocation of " +
                    (sCursorWindowSize / 1024) + " kb failed. " + printStats());
        }
        mCloseGuard.open("close");
        recordNewWindow(Binder.getCallingPid(), mWindowPtr);
    }
```

As you can see, `sCursorWindowSize` is the size that [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) has mentioned:

```
sCursorWindowSize = Resources.getSystem().getInteger(
                com.android.internal.R.integer.config_cursorWindowSize) * 1024;
```

As my current version is `Android SDK 23.0.1`, the value of `com.android.internal.R.integer.config_cursorWindowSize` is 2048. It means 2MB. I don't have another version SDK for checking.

Comment: It's defined as 2048 as far back as Android 4.0 which is as far as anyone supports I believe https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/fd1d05a01a704db47f6e60425c0ac3e1bd4cffbf/core/res/res/values/config.xml#L617

Answer (score 4):

Cursor doesn't contain all the results in memory but it does have the total count of the returned query (via getCount). While you iterate over the results it fetches the entries (not one by one I guess but probably in chunks). I'm pretty sure there are optimizations on this level. Once you're done with it you must close it - otherwise why would the system keep it open after the query has been already made.